# See over the rectangle a background image on mouse over using html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Here my code on jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/6u7bLkwc/

In order to reproduce my issue, please follow this steps:

- Click on the image and drag your mouse in order to create a rectangle.
- Once done, put your mouse over the rectangle, here come my issue, you will see a **black** rectangle.

I want when you mouse over a rectangle, you will see the image and not black color.

When i uncomment (ctx.clearRect) below:

```
function loop() {
  //ctx.clearRect(0,0,window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
```

And mouse over the rectangle, i see a grey color, it seem that we see the blank background ... i want see the image under the rectangle.

Comment: Hey it's my lion! *(always wanted to say this ;-) )*

Comment: @Kaiido loool yes ! is a great image  :D

Comment: PS : more seriously, your issue is that you never redraw your imageObj on the canvas in the loop, so all your almost transparent black rects ends up multiplied in an fully opaque rect. Just call `drawImage` in your loop and it's fixed : https://jsfiddle.net/6u7bLkwc/1/

Comment: @Kaiido Man !!! You are a boss ... i don't have point to up vote your answer ... but once i get them i will do it ... many thank's !!! you made my day :'(

Comment: @Kaiido Like promized i upvoted your comment ;)